# Manage list of members acording to active/inactive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby program in which Member model posses

has_many :earnings
earning

belongs_to :member

members has two kind

```html
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :kind %><br>
    <%= f.select :kind, ["active", "inactive"] %>
  </div>
```

```html
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :member %><br>
    <%= collection_select(:earning, :member_id, Member.all, :id, :bd, {}, {:multiple => false}) %>
  </div>
```

//////////////////////

I have made this selection bar in earning/new.html.erb. But I actually want to list the active members only. not the inactive members. they should remain hidden. I am using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.0.0p598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define a [**`scope`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your **`Member`** model like this

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active_members, -> { where(kind: 'active') }
end
```

And use this in the **`collection_select`** like this

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :member %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:earning, :member_id, Member.active_members, :id, :bd, {}, {:multiple => false}) %>
</div>
```